# What functions satisfy such equation?

Tags: analysis

Let $f:(-a,a)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a  continuous function such that
$$
f(0)=\frac{f(-x)+f(x)}{2} \textrm{ for } |x|<a.
$$

What about $f$? Is it necessarilly an odd function?

Comment: ...what about $f$? What do you want to know about $f$? (Other than whether or not it's odd.)

Comment: I want to know a general form of solution of that equation with unknow function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One thing is for sure, for $x\in (-a,a)$, $g(x):=f(x)-f(0)$ is an odd function. Apart from that nothing else seems to be evident.

Comment: And more to the point, any function of the form $f(x)=f(0)+g(x)$ with $g$ odd is a solution, so this completely classifies the set of solutions.

Comment: Yes, that's true Mario.

Comment: I would add that if it's not clear how you found these solutions, the OP should try a simple case: $f(0)=0$. Then draw pictures for $f(0)\neq0$.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Probably found it this way: $f(0)=\frac{f(-x)+f(x)}{2}\iff \frac{(f(-x)-f(0))+(f(x)-f(0))}{2}=0\iff f(-x)-f(0)=-(f(x)-f(0))$.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't have to be odd. Consider: $f(x)=x+1$

Answer (score 2):

f is not necessarily an odd function. Consider any constant function: f(x) = c. Any constant function satisfies the property you stated, but does not satisfy the properties of odd functions: f(-x) = - f(x) and f(x) + f(-x) = 0.